# How to sum up the resultes in a while loop while centain input will end the while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, sum

I have a situation in java;

I would like to ask the user to put in some numbers & have a total of those numbers. However if the user enter a negative number it will end the loop;

currently I have a while loop as below;

```
                double sum = 0;
    double Input = 0;
    System.out.println("Please enter the numbers (negative to end)")
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    Scanner kdb = new Scanner(System.in);
          Input = kdb.nextDouble();
    while (Input > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter an income");
        Input = kdb.nextDouble();
        sum = Input;
    }
```

However it does not do the job. If the user put in 40,60,50, and -1 the correct result should be 150; my loop result in 109.

Please help!

Many thanks!
Jackie

Comment: You have at least 2 problems.  #1 - Look at your code very carefully and tell us what happens - exactly - when a negative is entered.  #2 - explain to us how this is summing.

Answer (score 2):

```
double sum = 0;
double Input = 0;
System.out.println("Please enter the numbers (negative to end)")
System.out.println("Enter a number");
Scanner kdb = new Scanner(System.in);
Input = kdb.nextDouble();
while (Input > 0)
{
    sum += Input;
    System.out.println("Enter an income");
    Input = kdb.nextDouble();
}
```

I recommend variable names not to start with upper case letters.

Comment: I will also suggest to use `do-while` to execute this.

Comment: We should probably teach them to fish, not give them the fish.

Comment: @TonyEnnis I am agree with you. These are some very easy basic level things which should be researched.

Comment: @user1952050: hope you not simply take the code, but also think about what the difference to your code is.

Comment: @MrSmith42 this is a learning process. I was so stupid that tried 3 hours before you reminded me that I should sum before asking for nother num! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You should check for Input > 0 before doing sum += Input.

Answer (score 0):

This should work!

```
        double sum = 0;
    double Input = 0;
    boolean Adding= true;
    System.out.println("Please enter the numbers (negative to end)");

    Scanner kdb = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(Adding == true)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        Input = kdb.nextDouble();
        if(Input > 0)
        {
            sum+= Input;
        }
        else
            Adding = false;

    }
    System.out.println("Your sum is: " + sum);
```

Comment: `(Adding == true)` Whats wrong with `(Adding)` only? Moreover why is your varible name starts with capital letter?

Comment: MrSmith's code below is better.  Less logic less code same result.

Comment: Was never sure if that worked haha and to lazy to check. Ill use just (Adding) for now on.

Answer (score 0):

The first input value was overwritten by the second one since the the sum was done only at the end of the loop.

```
**double sum = 0;
double Input = 0;
System.out.println("Please enter the numbers (negative to end)");
System.out.println("Enter a number");
Scanner kdb = new Scanner(System.in);
      Input = kdb.nextDouble();
while (Input>0)
{
    sum+= Input;
    System.out.println("Enter an income");
    Input = kdb.nextDouble();

}
System.out.println(sum);
}**
```

The output is:

```
Please enter the numbers (negative to end)
```

Enter a number
40
Enter an income
50
Enter an income
60
Enter an income
-1
150.0